# .onblur function return as a variable.value?

Tags: javascript, function, events

http://jsfiddle.net/beY6d/

I want to make a simple HTML+JS page that basically gives the user 4 text fields to write the name of some product and an extra field that displays the remaining credit in the 5th text field.

```
<input type="text" value="0" class="product" id="shirtItems"/><br>
<input type="text" value="0" class="product" id="pantsItems"/><br>
<input type="text" value="0" class="product" id="hatItems"/><br>
<input type="text" value="0" class="product" id="accesoryItems"/><br>
<input type="text" value="100" id="credit" disabled/>
```

```
var shirt= document.getElementById("shirtItems");
var pants= document.getElementById("pantsItems");
var hat= document.getElementById("hatItems");
var accesory= document.getElementById("accesoryItems");
var remainingDosh = document.getElementById("credit");

remainingDosh.value = 100;
```

There must be a `.onblur` (or `.onfocus`) event to make the "*credit*" field display 100 minus the sum of every other item.

Also, the price of the item must change depending on the color/type of item. Something like:

```
shirt.onblur = function(){
    if (shirt.value == "Blue") {remainingDosh.value = remainingDosh-25}
    if (shirt.value == "Red") {remainingDosh.value = remainingDosh-20;}
};
```

Comment: *"to write the name of some product"* ? Can you be more specific?

Comment: remainingDosh is an element and you are treating it as a number.

Comment: If you show me an input field with value `0` it would never cross my mind to write inside it `"Blue"` or `"Red"`. Create radio buttons or checkboxes with labels for your users to click. Create a separate function that will run on change, blur and keyup and do your calculations.

Answer (score 5):

If you do `typeof remainingDosh.value`, you'll see that it logs `string`. This means you'll have to convert the string to a number if you don't want to risk having `NaN` show up on your page.

Convert it with `parseInt()` like so:

```
var remainingDosh.value = parseInt(remainingDosh,10)-25;
```

The second parameter, `10` is the radix, which in this case is decimal (though it defaults to decimal if left out I believe).

And the issue in question, as pointed out, is you're trying to do math on the element `remainingDosh` instead of using it's `value`.

Oh, and protip: instead of `shirt.value`, you can use `this.value` since the event comes from said element.

Comment: +1 (@user358blahblah) Also for a better UX a keyup listener would be nice. `blur` is not always obvious from a User perspective

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan yeah, I like `keyup` events better than `blur`s. But that's up to him/her I guess.

Answer (score 1):

you're using `remainingDosh` instead of `remainingDosh.value` when you do your subtraction.

Comment: Thanks man, it actually helped, problem now is if I write Blue on the first box (getting result of 75) and later  I change my mind and write Red, it is substracted from 75 (not 100).

Comment: @user3583763 Why let the users write stuff in your fields?? This in nonsense, create checkboxes or radio buttons (with Blue, Red... labels) for them to click!